# browser adding </div> in the wrong place

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code to loop through an object and display it in the browser:

```
function showSearchResults(resultsObj) {
    var results = resultsObj.hits
    for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
        resultsDiv.innerHTML += '<div class=\'ultimate-search-result\'>' + results[i].description;
        if (results[i].linktoken) {
            resultsDiv.innerHTML += '<a href=\'' + results[i].linktoken + '\'><i class=\'icon-pencil\'></li></a>';
        }
        if (results[i].linkpart) {
            resultsDiv.innerHTML += '<a href=\'' + results[i].linkpart + '\'><i class=\'icon-info-sign\'></li></a>';
        }
        resultsDiv.innerHTML += '</div>';
    }   
}
```

When I run the code in the browser the link icons appear underneath the description, when I inspect the code in Chrome the div is closed  at the end of the result description line instead of after the link icons while in the code the  is supposed to be inserted after the links. In Firefox I experienced the same problem.

Error can be seen in the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v6DjA/

Comment: 1st why update innerHTML in installments? Make a variable set all the strings and then add to innerHTML.

Comment: `<i class=\'icon-info-sign\'></li></a>` implies you have a missing `<li>` as you are closing the `</li>` without opening it anywhere. Invalid HTML will cause your browser to interpret the given HTML as best as it can.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/v6DjA/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright so the browser did not like how you were adding to the div. So break it up into a variable then append to that then add that to the innerHTML at the end. See example below.

```
var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class=\'ultimate-search-result\'>' + results[i].description;
    if (results[i].linktoken) {
        html += '<a href=\'' + results[i].linktoken + '\'>link 1</a>';
    }
    if (results[i].linkpart) {
        html += '<a href=\'' + results[i].linkpart + '\'>link 2</a>';
    }
    html += '</div>';
}
resultsDiv.innerHTML = html;
```

Here is a link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnstew/cFYX4/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write to `innerHTML` all at one time. The browser is seeing a `div` being added as part of `'<div class=\'ultimate-search-result\'>' + results[i].description` and automatically closing it since it thinks you left it out.

I recommend storing the new HTML in a var then write to `innerHTML` all at once:

```
function showSearchResults(resultsObj) {
    var results = resultsObj.hits;
    var html = '';
    for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
        html += '<div class=\'ultimate-search-result\'>' + results[i].description;
        if (results[i].linktoken) {
            html += '<a href=\'' + results[i].linktoken + '\'><i class=\'icon-pencil\'></li></a>';
        }
        if (results[i].linkpart) {
            html += '<a href=\'' + results[i].linkpart + '\'><i class=\'icon-info-sign\'></li></a>';
        }
        html += '</div>';

        //now write output
        resultsDiv.innerHTML = html;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser is closing the div for you on the first line.

```
    resultsDiv.innerHTML += '<div class=\'ultimate-search-result\'>' + results[i].description;
```

So you see the div ending after this.

```
htmlData = "";
for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
    htmlData += '<div class=\'ultimate-search-result\'>' + results[i].description;
    if (results[i].linktoken) {
        htmlData  += '<a href=\'' + results[i].linktoken + '\'><i class=\'icon-pencil\'></li></a>';
    }
    if (results[i].linkpart) {
        htmlData  += '<a href=\'' + results[i].linkpart + '\'><i class=\'icon-info-sign\'></li></a>';
    }
    htmlData  += '</div>';
}   
resultsDiv.innerHTML=htmlData;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6DjA/5/